# Problem of read only name using Jitsi Meet library

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, jitsi-meet

I am using Jitsi Meet library for a conference call in Android Studio project. It's working fine but the problem is I want to set each member's name with the person's profile name and the person could not change their name while joining. I have searched for this problem and I found that using `readOnlyName` will solve the problem but after using it's still not working. Also, I need that when the person creates the conference only the first person should be a moderator. My code just sets a moderator role for every person who joins the conference.

```
JitsiMeetUserInfo jitsiMeetUserInfo = new JitsiMeetUserInfo();
jitsiMeetUserInfo.setDisplayName(username);
jitsiMeetUserInfo.setEmail("abc@xyz.com");
        
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
    .setRoom(practice_edittext.getText().toString())
    .setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled",false)
    .setUserInfo(jitsiMeetUserInfo)
    .setConfigOverride("enableInsecureRoomNameWarning", false)
    .setConfigOverride("invite.enabled", false)
    .setFeatureFlag("readOnlyName", true)
    .setConfigOverride("hideAddRoomButton", false)
    .build();
    
JitsiMeetActivity.launch(Main_Activity.this,options);
```

I am using the latest version of Jitsi Meet library

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:6.2.0') { transitive = true }
```